# Creating a lightning invoice without running a full node

Tags: lightning-network, invoices

I'm trying to build a small website that takes payments using a lightning invoice. I want to do this without running a full node (or pruned node if possible) on my server to keep costs down. I'd be happy with any of three types of solutions:

1. Install a custodial lightning wallet on my server with a CLI or REST API to generate and check the status of a lightning invoice. [Electrum](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/) could work, but I didn't see invoice generation in the docs.
2. I already run a full node on Umbrel, but I'm not sure how to securely expose [lnd's http api](https://api.lightning.community/#lnd-rest-api-reference) to the internet.
3. Use someone else's full bitcoin node to back lnd on my server, or use a custodial lightning wallet with an api.

I'm open to suggestions, I'm very new to the space and learning lots all the time.

Ongoing research:

- [lightning-charge](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning-charge) uses [c-lightning](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning), which requires a full node.
- [FeatherLight](https://github.com/FeatherLightApp/FeatherLight-API) looks like it would do what I want as a standalone service, but again, I'd have to host a full node.
- [LightningHub API](https://yojoe.github.io/lightninghub-api/#addinvoice) Seems like it could work if I set up a BlueWallet.
- [LND Hub](https://github.com/BlueWallet/LndHub) provides multiple users access to a single lnd instance.

Comment: I can suggest also the following tools https://github.com/clightning4j where you can run c-lightning on a machine of 30 $ for a month. This is a demo https://bruce.bublina.eu.org/. The idea is to use the rest API with Nginx on docker so you can hide the API from the public, and talk with your website. A microservices architecture. P.S: it can support BOLT 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach I've ended up taking for this project is to expose my Umbrel's [LND gRPC REST API](https://api.lightning.community/#lnd-rest-api-reference).

My home network doesn't accept incoming requests, and I don't want that for my entire Umbrel anyway, so I'm using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to proxy requests to LND. LND only accepts TLS connections, so `bind_tls` has to be true, and `proto` should be set to `tls`. Ngrok has its own tls setup, so it doesn't bother to check the validity of LND's self-signed cert, and so doesn't need the path to the certfile.

I'm also using a restrictive macaroon for authentication — this is essential for security, since if the admin macaroon were leaked you'd be up a creek. In my case, all I had to do was generate and check invoices; `./umbrel/bin/lncli bakemacaroon uri:/lnrpc.Lightning/AddInvoice uri:/lnrpc.Lightning/LookupInvoice` was sufficient for that.

To make requests against my lightning node, all I have to do is something along the lines of `curl -X POST https://my-app.ngrok.io/v1/invoices -H "Grpc-Metadata-macaroon: my-macaroon" -d '{"amount":1000,"memo":"my-memo"}'`. This translates nicely to a python requests invocation from my application server.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain my comment in an answer. There is no clear way to host a lite ln client only to revive payment and show it, without hosting an ln node on the server, with the bitcoin core backend. Maybe with `lnd` you can do some things (or rust-lightning), but I'm not an expert of both implementation.

However, I worked on this problem in the last months, because I was searching for some things to make my c-lightning node a little bit more lite. With c-lightning, there is the opportunity to run custom code inside it, and I override the bitcoin backend with a custom plugin called [btcli4j](https://github.com/clightning4j/btcli4j) that is able to run c-lightning with the pruning mode, and also with rest API compatible with [esplora API](https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora) by default it uses Blockstream API.

There are a couple of tools that I developed to run c-lightning in a lite way for business and all the code is under the repository [clightning4j](https://github.com/clightning4j).

There is also a [docker image](https://github.com/clightning4j/clightning4j-node) that packs all together (include also a rest API documented with open API)

I think it is a really lite way solution because it can be run in raspberry with a default config (without 1TB of space). Off curse, the tools are under dev, but there is a [open discussion](https://github.com/clightning4j/JRPClightning/discussions) where you can make a feature request.

A demo available [here](https://bruce.bublina.eu.org/)

Running over [image]